# How to remove a 1-second appearance of scrollbars from a div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, stylesheet

site is [www.onlinefilmbox.com](http://www.onlinefilmbox.com)

When it loads, you can see that for a second, horizontal and vertical bars appear on the carousel in the center.

They appear for a second and then gone.

But I wonder - can I remove this short appearance?

I tried "overflow: hidden" and "overflow-x: hidden" + "overflow-y: hidden"
and both don't change anything.

any idea?

Comment: I can't reproduce your described problem (Firefox 3.6, Linux).

Comment: I don't see the problem either (Windows 7, IE8 64-bit).  You may be experiencing lag in the time it takes for your browser to parse the stylesheet.

Comment: I can see it in IE7, but can't speak for any other browsers at the moment - definitely looks like lag in the stylesheet loading.

Answer (score -1):

As the above commenters I don't see the problem either, but I'm pretty sure the problem is that the page loads slower with your computer or internet. I would suggest to use javascript or php to display the page after it's fully loaded. You could also try this:

```
scrolling = "none"
```

in the frame in html.

Comment: Using JavaScript to display the page after it has fully loaded will leave users staring at a blank screen for longer, this will lead to more of them giving up and going away, so it is a terrible idea.

Comment: You cannot use PHP to stop the page displaying before it is loaded.

Comment: There is no frame in the HTML so your third suggestion is as nonsensical as the second.

Comment: I'm not saying (s)he should let it leave blank for 2 seconds or something, it's probably a difference of like half a second. Of php i didn't know but it was merely a suggestion. As for the frame, it doesn't matter whether it's a frame or div to me, as long as the property has effect.

Comment: It isn't a property and won't have any effect.